# inter component communication in nuxt js

Tags: vue-component, nuxt.js

I am trying to call a function of a component from another component. 
In the called function there is a dispatch to store which works if call it from the same component but gives an error if the call is made from other components.
Same with the $emit and $on

---

Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

### Component from where the function is called

```
<template>
 <div>
   <button @click="doSubmit()">submit</button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import empinfo from '../components/empinfo'
    export default {
     components: {

      },
   data() {
     return {
      infoEmp: {

      }   
    }
  },
 methods: {
  doSubmit() {
  empinfo.methods.putEmpinfo()
  console.log('this sendEmpinfo', empinfo.methods.putEmpinfo())

  // this.$nuxt.$on('EMP_INFO', (data) => {
  //   this.infoEmp = data
  //   console.log('in data', data)
  // })
  console.log('infoEmp', this.infoEmp)
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

---

Here

### The function called

```
<script>
  export default {
   data() {
     return {
      empInfo: {
       lastName: "",
       firstName: "",
       middleIntial: "",
       otherLastName: "",
       address: "",
       apartmentNo: "",
       city: [],

     }
   }
 },
computed: {
compEmpinfo() {
  // console.log('emp inform', event)
  // this.$store.dispatch('formdata/EMP_INFO', this.empInfo)

  console.log("this is ", this)

  const some = this.$store.dispatch("formdata/EMP_INFO", this.empInfo)
  console.log("log sto", some)
  return some

  // return this.$nuxt.$emit('EMP_INFO', this.empInfo)
}
},

methods: {
  putEmpinfo() {
  // console.log('emp inform', event)
  // this.$store.dispatch('formdata/EMP_INFO', this.empInfo)

  //console.log("this is ", this)

  try {
    const some = this.$store.dispatch("formdata/EMP_INFO", 
this.empInfo)
    console.log("log some", some)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("try clatch", error)
  }
  // return this.$nuxt.$emit('EMP_INFO', this.empInfo)
},
testcall() {
  console.log("test call works")
},
sendEmpinfo() {
  return this.empInfo
  }
  }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: you shoudlnt import one component into other. you should communicate via store that is available in each component, without importing them

Comment: Yes, That's what I was intended to do, by making a call to that component where the store.dispatch is there but the error is saying the dispatch itself is undefined, it  is not executing the dispatch, and if you log "this"  then it is not showing it as a vue component.

Comment: because you are importing one component into otehr and try to execute its methods. That wont work this way like i said

Comment: https://medium.com/@Shardik/eventbus-for-nuxt-js-components-46660ae54f2d

on click of methods, you can emit event and receive in another component.
when emitting event you can send methods also in data in terms of object.

Comment: yeah, you were right @Aldarund, thanks. I used watch property to see the changes in data and then dispatch to store.